# SwiftUI - Pass user location information from LocationManager to another class

Tags: class, swiftui, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to pass the user's lat/long from my LocationManager to an API's call. I am able to successfully pass the value with the page's main view, but accessing it from within the RestaurantFetcher class I built for the API call returns nil.

I'm sure this is something simple that I just don't know, but how would I be able to grab that lat/long so that I can insert it into the API's call URL in my RestaurantFetcher class?

Here's the view code:

```
struct ExploreView: View {

@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
@ObservedObject var fetcher = RestaurantFetcher()

var body: some View {
    
    return ScrollView(.vertical) {
        HStack {
            Text("Latitude: \(locationManager.userLatitude)")
              //Returns valid latitude
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal)
        VStack {
            ForEach(fetcher.businesses) { restaurant in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: restaurant.image_url))
                        .resizable()
                        .indicator(.activity) // Activity Indicator
                        .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5)) // Fade Transition with duration
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 240, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                        
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(4)
                    
                    Text(restaurant.name)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    HStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                        Text(restaurant.price ?? "No Pricing Info")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("·")
                        ForEach(restaurant.categories, id: \.self) { cat in
                            Text(cat.title)
                                .font(.caption)
                        }
                        Text("·")
                    }
                    HStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("\(restaurant.rating, specifier: "%.1f")")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text("(\(restaurant.review_count))")
                            .font(.caption)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text(restaurant.location.city)
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.bottom)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
}
}

struct ExploreView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}


public class RestaurantFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var businesses = [RestaurantResponse]()
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

init() {
    load()
}
func load() {
    print("\(locationManager.userLongitude),\(locationManager.userLatitude)")
    //Returns nil
    let apikey = "API-KEY"
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?latitude=\(self.locationManager.userLatitude)&longitude=\(self.locationManager.userLongitude)&radius=40000")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("Bearer \(apikey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let d = data {
                let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode(BusinessesResponse.self, from: d)
                print("\(self.locationManager.userLongitude),\(self.locationManager.userLatitude)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.businesses = decodedLists.restaurants
                }
            } else {
                print("No Data")
            }
        } catch {
            print ("Caught")
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new instance of the `LocationManager` in both views. This means you're using *two* different instances:

```
struct ExploreView: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    ...
}

struct RestaurantFetcher: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    ...
}
```

So the `LocationManager` you access in the `ExploreView` is different from the one you access in the `RestaurantFetcher`. That's why `locationManager.userLatitude` returns different results.

You need to use *one* instance in both views:

```
struct ExploreView: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager
    @ObservedObject var fetcher: RestaurantFetcher
    
    init() {
        let locationManager = LocationManager()
        self.locationManager = locationManager
        self.fetcher = RestaurantFetcher(locationManager: locationManager)
    }
    ...
}
```

```
public class RestaurantFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var businesses = [RestaurantResponse]()
    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager // <- declare only

    init(locationManager: LocationManager) {
        self.locationManager = locationManager
        load()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The initializer for fetcher is throwing an error "self used before all stored properties are initialized"

Comment: @JasonTremain At which line? Remember to only declare the `LocationManager` in the `RestaurantFetcher`.

Comment: The line "fetcher = RestaurantFetcher(locationManager: locationManager)" And yes, I removed the duplicate declaration. I copied and pasted your code above.

Comment: @JasonTremain Oh, thanks, my bad. I updated my code.